# Using CSS Counters

Tags: css, css-counter

How can I count a element if each of them is nested in a sepereate element ?

```css
    .variant--name::before {
      counter-increment: section;
      content: "Abschnitt " counter(section) ": ";
    }
```

```html
<div class="variant--group">
<h3 class="variant--name">variant</h3>
</div>

<div class="variant--group">
<h3 class="variant--name">variant</h3>
</div>

<div class="variant--group">
<h3 class="variant--name">variant</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also need `counter-reset`

```css
body {
  counter-reset: section;
}
.variant--name::before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: "Abschnitt " counter(section)": ";
}
```

```html
<div class="variant--group">
  <h3 class="variant--name">variant</h3>
</div>
<div class="variant--group">
  <h3 class="variant--name">variant</h3>
</div>
<div class="variant--group">
  <h3 class="variant--name">variant</h3>
</div>
```

Edit: You can create **parent** element and use `counter-reset` on it, so now for every `parent` element you create new instance of counter [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/468/) instead of resetting counter on body [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/467/)